# UICollectionView Headers Overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionView with the following relevant methods:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
    Scoreboard *thisScoreboard = [self.scoreboards objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    ScoreboardReusableView *view = nil;

    view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                              withReuseIdentifier:@"scoreboardHeader"
                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
    //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ vs %@", thisScoreboard.awayteam, thisScoreboard.hometeam];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.section];


    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 34);
}
```

However, the label text is overlapping. Here are two screenshots of the collectionView. Sections 0 and 1 (notice how the text does NOT overlap):

[image]

And sections 2 and 3 (the text overlaps here and on all subsequent section headers):
[image]

My header xib `ScoreboardReusableView` is COMPLETELY blank because no matter what I put in it (e.g., a UILabel or a UIImageView, it would not show up in the UICollectionView Header). Preferably I would design the header in a xib, but since that's not working I tried to do it programmatically, but now labels are overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection views re-use cells and headers. When a header is scrolled offscreen it is added to a queue, and will be re-used for the next header to be scrolled onscreen. That means your configuration code in `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:` method will be run again on the same header view at different indexPaths. Since you're just adding a label every time your configuration code runs, they will stack one on top of the other.

The correct approach is to have a label property on the headerView, so that its text can be changed. But...

> no matter what I put in it (e.g., a UILabel or a UIImageView), it would not show up

This is your real issue. Do you have autolayout enabled on the xib? If so be sure to add constraints for the label, otherwise it will have zero width and height, giving the effect you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version, hope it helps

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    var reusableview: UICollectionReusableView?
    reusableview = nil
    reusableview = playersCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "collViewHeader", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {

        //remove all previous subviews:
        if let views = reusableview?.subviews {
            for view in views {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        //----------

        if reusableview == nil {
            reusableview = UICollectionReusableView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
        }

        //init label
        let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 20.0, width: self.view.frame.width-20, height: 25.0)) //-20 from width to make it no go out of screen bounds
        label.textColor = UIColor.blue //you may set your color here :)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.text = "your text here"

        reusableview?.addSubview(label)
    }
    return reusableview!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ScoreboardReusableView is blank but it was reusable. You must put UILabel into header xib and set text for it after that.

For example:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        Scoreboard *thisScoreboard = [self.scoreboards objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        ScoreboardReusableView *view = nil;

        view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                          withReuseIdentifier:@"scoreboardHeader"
                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];

        view.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.section];

        return view;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: When I put a UILabel into ScoreboardReusableView and set the text of that label property, the UILabel doesn't appear at all. If I set the background color of the xib, that doesn't appear either.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview=nil;
    reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [reusableview subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if (reusableview==nil) {
        reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 30)];
    }
    reusableview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:234.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel *lblTitle=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-90, 30)];
    [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Light" size:12]];

    lblTitle.textColor=HTAtHomeColor;
    [reusableview addSubview:lblTitle];

    UILabel *lblCount=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-80, 0, 70, 30)];
    lblCount.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
    lblCount.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [lblCount setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Light" size:12]];
     lblCount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Section Header",indexPath.row];


    [reusableview addSubview:lblCount];

    return reusableview;
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: This Code will solve the header overlapping problem in collection view

Comment: thanks it helped me a lot but i needed to rewrite it into swit)